# Play games on my TV as a second display while working on the primary screen

Tags: monitor

I connected my TV(located in another room) to my pc with long HDMI cable to play games on it while working at the same time on primary screen
Monitor = Primary screen & TV = Secondary screen.
I installed dual monitor tools and I can move the game screen to my TV without any problem (I selected Extend option on my win 10)
also I have a wireless game controller and I can control the game with it.
the problem starts when I want to work on my Monitor (Primary screen) at the same time.
as soon as I click on my monitor the game pause on my TV and I have to click on game icon on the taskbar to resume the game again
is there any solution to solve this issue ?
can I play game on my TV and work on my monitor at the same time ?

Comment: It depends on the game. Some allow borderless windowed mode that can accomplish this, some have borderless windowed mode that minimizes the game no matter what. There isn't a "fix works everywhere" solution.

Comment: This pretty much isn't any different to any dual monitor set up, and running a game on either monitor. For instance this problem exists if you wish to use your primary monitor for gaming, and your second monitor for anything else. If you are using "full screen" the game will always pause/minimise, which is Windows-specific behaviour you can't change. As Kaizerwolf mentions, you need to look into running your games as "Windowed borderless"

Comment: I'm not sure that the "windowed borderless" display option would help either, unless the question is using a weird definition of "at the same time" (or a weird definition of "work", I suppose). It may prevent the automatic pausing and/or minimising that occurs when you switch applications, but switching applications is *still* going to cause the game to lose focus and as a result it likely won't recognise any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

For work, it depends on what work you want to do, but it would be hard to make it work.

Most games need to be the active window to accept input, and also, most work software needs focus to accept any click or keyboard inputs. And its built into windows pretty deep that there can only be ONE active window.

Even if you could have multiple active windows, you would have to be able to untangle outputs, like if you are writing a report you don't want to open the inventory of the player every time you press I; and also untangle audio outputs (not that hard to do under Windows 10, but yeah, still annoying)

I would say that because of the first 2 problems I listed, it is impossible to do what you ask, that one window be a game and the second be work.

The only work you can do while doing so would be passive work. If you need to watch a video or a livestream for a formation/conference, then you could put the sound of Chrome or Zoom on your headphones, and the sound of the game on the TV or the headphones of the player.

Comment: If I scroll in a game, and I have discord or twitter open on another monitor, it will scroll that other application as well. Just a fundamental windows function/feature/headache.